# Typing array item in TS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

Do I need to define array items type in loop functions (`map`/`filter`/`find`/...)?

For example, I have an array:

```
const arr: { lastName: string, age: number }[]
```

Pushing 2 items:

```
arr.push({firstName: 'Messi', age: 35})
arr.push({firstName: 'Ronaldo', age: 37})
```

Now, I want to iterate over this array using `map`:

```
const result = arr.map(player => "My last name is: " player.lastName)
```

Do I need to define player's type even though the array is defined?
For example:

```
const result = arr.map(player: { lastName: string, age: number } => "My last name is: " player.lastName)
```

Comment: No that is not needed. Typescript (and your IDE) is able to infer the type from the `arr` type when mapping over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Typescript can infer type of player. You can read this official doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html